# How to show a certain value instead of None in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django and I am passing on object `players`
to my HTML template. I am iterating over this object and showing `player.lastName` but this value sometimes return None. How can I show a value of my choice if the `player.lastName` was None.

I want to write something like:

```
 {% for player in players %}
<td>{{player.lastName 'OR' - }}
```

Current Behavior would show

```
<td> LastName 1 </td>
<td> None </td>
<td> LastName 3 </td>
```

But What I want to show

```
 <td> LastName 1 </td>
<td> - </td> // folowing the OR ( since Value was none show "-"
<td> LastName 3 </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with the [**`|default_if_none`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none):

```
<td>{{player.lastName|default_if_none:"-" }}</td>
```

or use the [**`|default`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default) if you want to print the alternative if the item evaluates to `False` (so `False`, `None`, `''` empty string, `0`, etc.):

```
<td>{{player.lastName|default:"-" }}</td>
```